# How to make methods in ReactiveCrudRepository @Tailable

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I was looking into some tutorials on how to write Tailable cursor queries for capped collections in MongoDB. And I found out that I can achieve this using `@Tailable`. Fo example, like this:

```
public interface ReactiveProductRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Product, String>{

  @Tailable
  Flux<Product> findByName(String name);
}
```

This works like a charm. And also this works with `@Query` annotations (in case of complex queries).

But what if I want to make one of the methods in `ReactiveCrudRepository` as Tailable? For example, `findAll`. The only alternative I could find was to add a method like this in my repository:

```
  @Tailable
  @Query("{}")
  Flux<Product> findAllProducts();
```

which is nothing but findAll. I am wondering: Shouldn't there be an option to specify `@Tailable` feature for inbuilt methods?

Any thoughts? Does it make sense to have a new interface (`TailableRepository`) similar to `PagingAndSortingRepository`.

Comment: You probably want also to have methods which call complete. So why not to add single methods you really need as tailable as needed?

Answer (score 2):

Repository methods backed by an actual implementation can't be altered in their behavior or overwritten by a query method.

You can declare a query method without a parameter and provide a `default` implementation for the desired method you want to use as entry point:

```
public interface LoginEventRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<LoginEvent, String> {

    @Tailable
    Flux<LoginEvent> findPeopleBy();

    @Override
    default Flux<LoginEvent> findAll(){
        return findPeopleBy();
    }
}
```

See also [here](https://github.com/mp911de/reactive-spring/blob/master/spring-data/src/main/java/workshop/LoginEventRepository.java#L26-L30) for an example for a `@Tailable`, parameter-less query method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am afraid, this doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use findWithTailableCursorBy to retrieve all records without query

```
@Tailable
Flux<Product> findWithTailableCursorBy();
```